# How do I migrate VBA to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, vba

I have an MS-Access 2003 front end (backend SQL2000) that I want to move to asp.net. The system is too hungry bandwidth wise to run across the web/vpn.

I have started manually building the aspx and ascx's, which is becoming a bit of a nightmare, and will start on the code shortly.

Has anyone successfully migrated MS-Access/vba to asp.net?
Or any ideas of the correct (or just good) way to do this port?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it will really be much of a 'port'.  You will probably find that a complete re-write from requirements is required.  For a good tutorial on, IMHO, the best way to structure a data centric ASP.NET application, have a look [here](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=416) and [here](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=476).